# Jquery Dialog Font Size

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How do I change the font size of the Jquery UI dialog button before it opens and for a generic button? Which attribute is it?

Answer (score 2):

You may try it with css,

```
#dialogBox .ui-button-text {
    font-size: 10px; /* change font size */
    padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px; /* change padding */
}
```

or else with Jquery,

```
$(".ui-button-text").css({"font-size": +10+"px"});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS's `font-size` property:

```
button {
  font-size: 28px;
}
```